# How do we extend our privacy on TOR circuit?

Tags: configuration, onion-services, exit-relays, onion-routing, network-configuration

*The Tor Browser bounces your communications data through distributed network of relays by encrypting traffic in at least three layers
selected from thousands of volunteer computers, thus making incredibly difficult for anyone to trace you and your activity and identity 
that has been masked by Tor.*

Tor functions like a layered series of proxy servers that route your traffic in a zig-zag around the internet before it reaches your destination (the layers give rise to the name, which stands for The Onion Router).

There are at least three hops through data travels.

The entry node, which inevitably knows your IP address
The middle (or relay) node, which prevents the exit node from finding out which entry node you used and makes it very hard to correlate this information
The exit node, which knows what site you are connecting to, but does not know who you are

What if a malicious Tor node may keep limited logs and that parts of it may be under surveillance.

But since it’s not completely secure, because they previously had to rely on exit nodes. 
Since Exit nodes can also see your traffic and may attempt to modify it. 
But unfortunately it’s unlikely that resources will be spent tracking down your browsing habits running on a high-profile user
and these exit node bandwidth is the scarcest resource in the Tor ecosystem.

What measures should be taken in-order to avoid the above circumstances. What must be the additional softwares needed to be installed to combat against privacy?

How do we need to configure those Exit nodes? Does Onion Service really defend against the above scenario?

Comment: Can you try rewording your question, it’s unclear to me what you’re asking. Are you asking about traffic correlation attacks? Or malicious exit nodes modifying the data? In general you shouldn’t need any other software than the Tor Browser (and browse https webpages) to be reasonably safe. Onion services are designed more to protect the privacy of the server, so they will have little effect on the privacy of the user.

Comment: Both traffic correlation attacks and malicious exit nodes both are vulnerable to attacks. Since there are proven results. @Steve